# Getting value of any datatype from the user in Java and finding to which class it belongs to

Tags: java

I want to get a value from the user. The entered value may belong to any class. 
After getting the input, I would want to check its datatype. 
Not providing any restriction to the type of data the user should enter. 
For example, if he enters 4.56, the output should be float, if he enters "random", the output should be java.lang.String etc. Is it possible to write such a method in Java?

Comment: yes, but it 'll be a bit messy. for instance: 4 can be a String, an int, a short, ... so how will you decide?

Comment: Even if you manage this, what do you do of that value afterwards?

Comment: Do you need to consider i18n? i.e. in Germany you use the comma as decimal separator, so the user would enter 4,56.

Comment: Hmmmm interesting, just as an idea to begin with...I would develop something using generics and then hardcode checks using `regex` or parse methods like `Integer.ParseInt()`.

Answer (score 0):

`variable.getClass().getName()` will get you the type of value of the variable.

if you want to validate, you can use `instanceof`

```
if(variable instanceof String){}
```

There is also `variable.getClass().getSimpleName()` to get the name of type

Comment: The user wants to check the datatype of value entered by the user. Your solution assumes that the user entered the value, which got stored in the correct variable type (like if user entered 9.51 it got stored in float) and then you are reading that variable's type.